# Bottom borders radius not showing on webpage

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with right and left bottom radius borders on a div tag.

I am using a main div where I want radius borders on left and right bottom :

```
.main_div {

display:block;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 798px;

border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;

-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
-o-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000, Direction=180, Strength=30);
}
```

On jsfiddle, these borders radius are displayed : here the link[where it works](https://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/mbar8Lvq/2/)

Now, on another server, they don't appear : here the link [where it doesn't work][2]

I can't find out where it could come from, if anyone had an idea ...

Thanks

[2]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a table inside, you need to hide the overflow

```css
.main_div {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 798px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
  -o-box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 30px 10px #000000;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000, Direction=180, Strength=30);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works on both places. But there is an image covering it where you say it does not work.

You can check it by commenting the following CSS.

```
td.bottom_page {
    /* background-image: url(../images_template/header2_bg.jpg); */
}
```

To make sure the above background image only show up inside the `.main_div` allowing the bottom border radius to be visible, add `overflow: hidden;` to `main_div` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Add `border-radius` this class `td.bottom_page`

```
td.bottom_page {
    background-image: url("../images_template/header2_bg.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```